# Subqueries with Like, count, group by

Tags: mysql

My table:

```
 +----+------------+-------+-------+
 | id |    Name    |  Type |  Code |
 +----+------------+-------+-------+
 |  1 | /Color     | black | cod-1 |
 |  2 | Colorless  | black | cod-2 |
 |  3 | Colorful   | black | cod-1 |
 |  4 | Color/     | black | cod-3 |
 |  5 | Colored    | blue  | cod-1 |
 |  6 | Bottle     | black | cod-1 |
 |  7 | Bottles    | black | cod-2 |
 |  8 | Bottle/z   | black | cod-1 |
 |  9 | Bottleneck | blue  | cod-1 |
 +----+------------+-------+-------+
```

For a selected Type, I need to group by (like) Names and count by distinct code.

In the end, the final count must give:

```
 Type     Name like     Count Code

 Black      Color            3

 Black     Bottle            2

 Blue       Color            1

 Blue      Bottle            1
```

... and so on for unpredictable and randomized thousands of names containing a similar sequence of characters.
So far, any attempt was unsuccessfully. Any clue ?

Comment: So what determines `like` names... Need some sort of lookup table to determine that one.  Technically `o` in `color` is like `o` in `bottle`...

Answer (score 1):

To accomplish what you want I think you either need a lookup table from which you can match the names (a table holding synonyms), or you could hard code the logic like this:

```
SELECT 
    type AS "Type", 
    CASE 
       WHEN name LIKE '%Color%' THEN 'Color' 
       WHEN name LIKE '%Bottle%' THEN 'Bottle' 
    END AS "Name",
    COUNT(DISTINCT code) AS "Count Code" 
FROM your_table
GROUP BY 
    type, 
    CASE 
       WHEN name LIKE '%Color%' THEN 'Color' 
       WHEN name LIKE '%Bottle%' THEN 'Bottle' 
    END 
ORDER BY type
```

This would give you the result you want, as seen in this [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d1484/6). **This is obviously not a good solution - using a lookup table would be a lot better.**

Using a lookup table could be done like this:

```
create table lookup (k varchar(20), v varchar(30));
insert into lookup values 
('Bottle','Bottle'),('Bottle','Bottles'),
('Bottle','Bottle/z'),('Bottle','Bottleneck'),
('Color','Color'),('Color','Colorless'),
('Color','Colorful'),('Color','/Color'),
('Color','Color/'),('Color','Colored');

SELECT 
    type AS "Type", 
    l.k AS "Name",
    COUNT(DISTINCT code) AS "Count Code" 
FROM your_table tbl
INNER JOIN lookup l on tbl.name = l.v
GROUP BY type, l.k
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ffcef/1) using lookup table.

Comment: Codes are perfect for the example (too complicated for me!). Anyway, the above table is an extreme simplification of reality, in which there are thousands of UNPREDICTABLE and RANDOMIZED names, but containing a similar sequence of characters. So, I cannot predict how they would look like in the table. In this context, it seems that the lookup table doesn't accomplish what I need because I cannot know a priori which name will be inserted and how it will be written.
In fact, names, types and codes are uploaded via a form and anyone uses a "personal and not uniform way" to insert data.

Comment: @Wailmanager No, in the case you describe it might be hard to get it to work. I would guess that the best option might be to limit what gets entered at the UI level but maybe that's not an option.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
Select distinct Type, Name, count(code) from MyTable
    group by Type, Name
```

Comment: This won't do what the OP asks for.

Comment: @hamala94 I totally agree with jpw